# styling jquery div in css

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

why I am not able to style this by giving a class

```
<div class="ko">add image</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6MmMe/27/

```
$("div").hover(
  function () {
    $("<div class="ko">add image</div>").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().unbind("hover").children("img").attr("src", "http://www.onlinegrocerystore.co.uk/images/goodfood.jpg");
        $(this).remove();
    }).appendTo(this);
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).find("div:last").remove();
  }
);



//li with fade class
    //$("li.fade").hover(function(){$(this).fadeOut(100);$(this).fadeIn(500);});
```

Comment: Holy cow, messy code. =/

Comment: i made hover to img tag its not working jsfiddle.net/6MmMe/31 whats the reason

Comment: Images are empty you cannot append to them.

Answer (score 3):

You've closed the string that you use to create the div by wrapping the class name in double quotes.  Use single quotes (inside double quotes) to stop this happening....

```
$("div").hover(
    function () {
        $("<div class='ko'>add image</div>").click(function() {
            $(this).parent().unbind("hover").children("img").attr("src", "http://www.onlinegrocerystore.co.uk/images/goodfood.jpg");
            $(this).remove();
        }).appendTo(this);
    }, 
    function () {
        $(this).find("div:last").remove();
    }
);
```

See this update fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/6MmMe/28/

Comment: @archer: i made hover to img tag its not working http://jsfiddle.net/6MmMe/31/ whats the reason

Answer (score 0):

```
$("<div class=\"ko\">add image</div>")
```

Comment: i made hover to img tag its not working jsfiddle.net/6MmMe/31 whats the reason

Comment: I guess you cannot append to "img" tag, use some container like div to achieve your functionality. try this one http://jsfiddle.net/6MmMe/35/